# Storing the summary of a manova operation in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, manova

I'm new  to R and was trying to store the summary of a "manova" operation in a data frame. Is it possible to do so. If not a data frame, in what type can I store the summary of a "manova" operation. I tried converting it into a list and then placing it in  a data frame but its not possible to do so.

Here is the data:

```
Customer_Age<-c(45,51,40,44,51,32)   

Dependent_count<-c(3,3,3,2,4,0)      


Education_Level<-c("High School","Grad","Uneducated","Grad","High School","Grad")      

df_man<-data.frame(Education_Level,Customer_Age,Dependent_count)     

manovadf<-manova(cbind(Customer_Age,Dependent_count)~Education_Level,df_man)      

manovasum<-summary(manovadf)
```

When I'm trying to convert it into a data frame, getting the following error:

```
data.frame(manovasum)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
cannot coerce class ""summary.manova"" to a data.frame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you have to extract each attribute from mannova object using `$` operator. It's true for all model objects in R. For tidying this objects and converting them into a data.frame, try `broom` package

```
library(broom)

M <- mannova(...)
tidy(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `capture.output` function, if you don't want to perform further arithmetic operations on the result

```
output <- capture.output(manovasum)
```